# Converting objects in file to json in python

Tags: python, json

I have a file with multiple objects like this:

```
{ 
    name: (sindey, crosby)
    game: "Hockey"
    type: athlete
},
{ 
    name: (wayne, gretzky)
    game: "Ice Hockey"
    type: athlete
}
```

...and I'd like to convert them to JSON format and output this:

```
[
    { 
        "name": "(sindey, crosby)",
        "game": "Hockey",
        "type": "athlete"
    },
    { 
        "name": "(wayne, gretzky)",
        "game": "Ice Hockey",
        "type": "athlete"
    }
]
```

If the input was in this format,

```
 name: (sidney, crosby) | game:"Hockey" |  type:athlete 
 name: (wayne, gretzky) | game:"Ice Hockey" |  type:athlete
```

I could implement using json dump with list and dict and it gives me the desired output

```
import json

f = open("log.file", "r")
content = f.read()
splitcontent = content.splitlines()

d = []
for v in splitcontent:
    l = v.split(' | ')
    d.append(dict(s.split(':',1) for s in l))


with open("json_log.json", 'w') as file:
    file.write((json.dumps(d, indent=4, sort_keys= False)))
```

How can I reformat this code to convert my input to JSON format?

Comment: The names in the 2 formats are different.

Comment: @ScottHunter fixed, they're both meant to be in the same format.

Comment: Can you have your example of the first format show 2 objects?

Comment: Let's be clear: you have a non-standard file format and you have to write a parser for it. You wrote one for your other non-standard format; what is stopping your from writing one for your first one?

Comment: @chepner I'm getting confused with the split content part, I'm a beginner with python and don't know how fix it for the format I have

Comment: Please show what you have tried & what *specific* issues you are having with it.

Comment: You should be able to do something similar to your sample code, but split on newlines ("\n") rather than on "|"

Comment: @ScottHunter I tried splitting on newlines, please check update

Comment: @SarahMesser thank you for the suggestion, it gave me a length error, any way to fix it?

Comment: Note that now some of your lines (i.e. the ones with just braces) don't have any content to split.

Comment: @SarahMesser: Doesn't `splitlines` already handle that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With slight changes on the answer given by @sarah Messer. Changes involved

> lines without the : separator  skipped

Try this

```
import json


f = open("log.file", "r")
content = f.read()
splitcontent = content.splitlines()

d = []
appendage = {}
for line in splitcontent:

    if ('}' in line) or ('{' in line) or ('{' in line) or ('}' in line):
        # Append a just-created record and start a new one
        if appendage:
            d.append(appendage)
            appendage = {}
        continue

    key, val = line.split(':')

    if val.endswith(','):
        # strip a trailing comma
        val = val[:-1]
        print(val)
    # if val == "":
    #     pass
    # else:
    appendage[key] = val


with open("json_log.json", 'w') as file:
    file.write((json.dumps(d, indent=4, sort_keys=False)))
```

Comment: any idea why it's outputting only the 2nd object 6 times. The output is in the format I needed but outputs the (wayne, gretzky).... object 6 times

Comment: @learner22 checkout the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will probably work for most cases - you just have to handle the lines with curly braces separately from the lines with data:

```
import json

f = open("log.file", "r")
content = f.read()
splitcontent = content.splitlines()

d = []
appendage = {}
for line in splitcontent:
    if ('}' in line) or ('{' in line):
        # Append a just-created record and start a new one
        if appendage:
            d.append(appendage)
        appendage ={}
    else:
        key, val = line.split(':',1)
        if val.endswith(','):
            # strip a trailing comma
            val = val[:-1]
        appendage[key] = val


with open("json_log.json", 'w') as file:
    file.write((json.dumps(d, indent=4, sort_keys= False)))
```

I might also have some typos in there...